# store `CalendarData` locally in a file and load it to a computer without internet

Tags: date-and-time

How to download the `CalendarData` indices and locally store them in a file for the computer (server) where the internet connection is not available. To run command like the following:

`DateRange[{2012, 12, 31}, {2013, 12, 31}, "EndOfMonth"]`

`CalendarData::dlfail: Internet download of data for CalendarData failed. Use Help > Internet Connectivity... to test or reconfigure internet connectivity.`

Comment: With 11.2 I don't seem to need internet to get the list of dates.

Comment: there are some import mechanism bugs/changes in 11.2 for CSV which prevent me to update to 11.2. Is there a way to fix this for the older version 11.1.1?

Comment: This works for me : `Import@Export["/tmp/dr.csv", 
  DateRange[{2012, 12, 31}, {2013, 12, 31}, "EndOfMonth"]]`.

Comment: This would work for the particular expression. What i want to know is where does the downloaded `CalendarData` stored by Mathematica.